# Anything installed via homebrew throws 'command not found'

Tags: macos, homebrew, nvm

I've recently had some issues setting up my new mac with homebrew and npm. I've installed npm and node via nvm (not homebrew). For example, I installed yarn via homebrew and when i run `yarn` i get `bash: yarn: command not found` however if i run `brew list` I see yarn as one of the installations.

I have read that this usually has to do with my path being incorrect however I do see `/usr/local/bin` in my $PATH when I echo: `/Users/sydney/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Do I need to change the path order? Will this break any dependencies for nvm? This is not just happening for yarn but any package i install via homebrew (I've just attempted to install kubernetes-cli with the same results)

Comment: Try running `hash -r` to clear your shell's internal hash of where it thinks binaries are located - then it will have to consult your PATH to rebuild its hash correctly.

Comment: Dang, just tried that and still nothing. Thanks for the suggestion